# How do you animate with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got some frustration with ng-animate. I've spent two days reading about it, and I still don't understand how it works. Here is what I'm doing.

I have an element that I can drag around with my mouse. When the element reaches a specific threshold (130px left or right), I want to reset and animate it back to it's original position (0).

My element isn't entering, or leaving the Dom; and even though it's "moving" it's not changing it's position within the DOM, so it's not really "**ng-move**"ing.

**UPDATE**

By popular request, here's some code

```
app.directive('ngSwipeMessage', function ($touch, $animate) {

        const leftThreshold = -130;
        const rightThreshold = 130;

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, attr, controller) {

                var handler = $touch.bind(element, {
                    start: function (touch, ev) {
                        console.log("start");
                    },
                    end: function (touch, ev) {
                        console.log("end");
                        // if they stop moving, then reset
                        //$animate.addClass(element, "ng-move ng-move-active");
                    },
                    move: function (touch, ev) {
                        console.log("move");

                        element.css({
                            left: touch.distanceX
                        });

                        if (touch.distanceX < leftThreshold || touch.distanceX > rightThreshold) {
                            // fire our handler action and reset the element position
                            //$animate.addClass(element, "ng-move ng-move-active");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    console.log("destroying");
                    handler();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And here is the CSS

```
#list-messages .message.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s linear all;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear all;
  transition: 0.2s linear all;
  /* future proof */
}
#list-messages .message.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

So the things I've tried using is $animate.leave/enter/move but they appear to actually want to leave, enter, or move around the DOM. I've started experimenting with addClass/removeClass, which has shown some promise. Overall, creating a custom animation isn't (in my opinion) documented very well.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Matt, this is kinda neat: [link](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/) drag that blue button on that page ---
"angular-dragdrop" is a wrapper for jQueryUI draggable/droppable components.

Comment: @Shehryar That is neat. Thanks for the share. Any chance you've got a CSS solution too?

Comment: See this [link](http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html) for a pure Javascript + CSS solution, with CSS only asserting that the element be position:absolute. Additionally, this [link](http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html) creates custom Directives for AngularJS (does not use JQueryUI) . hope this helps. GL!

Comment: @Matt why don't you share some code showing a bit of what you've been doing.  As it stands, this question is lacking clarity.